# How to consider ions charges while calculating ions steady-state equilibrium concentration

Tags: cell-biology, cell-membrane

i recently tried to find answer for following problem:

> "Assume that a membrane is permeable to Ca++ , K+ and Cl- but not to a
>   large cation R+. The inside concentrations are [RCl] = 100mM and
>   [CaCl2] = 200mM, and the outside concentration is [CaCl2] = 300mM. (a)
>   Derive the Donnan equilibrium. (b) Find the steady-state equilibrium
>   concentration for Ca++."

when i tried to write space charge neutrality equation, i encounter to a new question,
how should i consider that

```
a:for each Ca++ there is two Cl-
```

and

```
b:each Ca++ has 2 positive charge
```

in the past i only worked with the ions that had same charge or same number of molecule, for example considering we had only cl- and K+ and some large
cation R+ , this situation is simple but the above mentioned problem is totally different.